# New command not making a new object C++

Tags: c++, object, queue, instance

I will start by explaining my issue, and then provide a good portion of the code.
I and filling a queue with a custom class called process. Using this line:

```
ProcessQueue.push(new Process(inputs[0], inputs[1], inputs[2], inputs[3], inputs[4]));
```

This all seems well and good, when the loop is done Process queue is filled with pointers.
However upon further inspection I found out they all point to the SAME object?

Finding this curious, I stepped into the constructor on each iteration of the loop.

> First iteration: when the constructor is entered all instance variables are null (as expected)
>
> Second iteration: upon entering the constructor, all instance variables contain the values given to the object in the first iteration (ie: the same object)

Furthermore later when I use the queue I have confirmed that every pointer in the queue is referring to the same process object. (I can tell this because process contains a state and if loop through the queue changing the state, I will find the state already changed for the second pointer)

I suspect I must have done something wrong with the creation of me class. so here it is in its entirety.

Process.h

```
    #pragma once
    class Process
    {
    public:
        Process(int _processId, int _arrivalTime, int _CPUTime,
            int _IOFrequency, int _IODuration);
        ~Process();

        bool HasArrived(int time);
        bool HasCompleted();
        bool HasFinishedBurst();
        bool HasFinishedIO();
        int GetQueueNum();
        int GetID();
        void SetQueueNum(int i);
        void SetToReady();
        void Run();
        void PerformIO();
    };
```

Process.cpp

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include "Process.h"
    #include <string>

    using namespace std;

    int processId;
    int arrivalTime;
    int CPUTime;
    int IOFrequency;
    int IODuration;

    int Ticks;
    int CPUConsumption;
    int CPUBurstSize;
    int queueNumber;
    int IOBurstCount;
    string state;


    Process::Process(int _processId, int _arrivalTime, int _CPUTime,
        int _IOFrequency, int _IODuration)
    {
        processId = _processId;
        arrivalTime = _arrivalTime;
        CPUTime = _CPUTime;
        IOFrequency = _IOFrequency;
        IODuration = _IODuration;
        IOBurstCount = 0;
        CPUConsumption = 0;
        Ticks = 0;
        queueNumber = 0;

        state = "None";
        printf("%d: %s\n", processId,state.c_str());

        int excess = CPUTime % IOFrequency;
        if (excess == 0)
        {
            CPUBurstSize = CPUTime / IOFrequency;
        }
        else
        {
            CPUBurstSize = (CPUTime - excess) / (IOFrequency - 1);
        }
    }

    Process::~Process()
    {
    }

    bool Process::HasArrived(int time)
    {
        if (arrivalTime <= time)
        {
            if (state.compare("Newly Arrived") == 0)
            {
                printf("Already arrived!\n");
            }
            state = "Newly Arrived";
            printf("%d: %s\n", processId, state.c_str());
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

    }

    bool Process::HasCompleted()
    {
        if (CPUConsumption == CPUTime && IOBurstCount == IOFrequency)
        {
            state = "Finished";
            printf("%d: %s\n", processId, state.c_str());
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    bool Process::HasFinishedBurst()
    {
        if (Ticks == CPUBurstSize)
        {
            Ticks = 0;
            state = "Blocked";
            printf("%d: %s\n", processId, state.c_str());
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    bool Process::HasFinishedIO()
    {
        if (Ticks >= IODuration)
        {
            IOBurstCount++;
            Ticks = 0;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    void Process::SetToReady()
    {
        state = "Ready";
        printf("%d: %s\n", processId, state.c_str());
    }

    void Process::Run()
    {
        state = "Running";
        printf("%d: %s\n", processId, state.c_str());
        Ticks++;
        CPUConsumption++;
    }

    void Process::PerformIO()
    {
        Ticks++;
    }

    int Process::GetQueueNum()
    {
        return queueNumber;
    }

    void Process::SetQueueNum(int i)
    {
        queueNumber = i;
    }

    int Process::GetID()
    {
        return processId;
    }
```

I suspect I have somehow created this as a static class without meaning too...

Comment: If you find this looks familiar....I accidentally deleted my old question....still new at this. So I rephrased it with what I had learned

Comment: Where is ProcessQueue defined? Show that code.

Comment: _'I found out they all point to the SAME object?'_ How exactly did you check this? Checking the addresses or content?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems you have placed all your member variables outside the class!

```
int processId;
int arrivalTime;
int CPUTime;
int IOFrequency;
int IODuration;

int Ticks;
int CPUConsumption;
int CPUBurstSize;
int queueNumber;
int IOBurstCount;
string state;
```

Should be here:

```
class Process
{
public:
    Process(int _processId, int _arrivalTime, int _CPUTime,
        int _IOFrequency, int _IODuration);
    ~Process();

    bool HasArrived(int time);
    bool HasCompleted();
    bool HasFinishedBurst();
    bool HasFinishedIO();
    int GetQueueNum();
    int GetID();
    void SetQueueNum(int i);
    void SetToReady();
    void Run();
    void PerformIO();

private:
   int processId;
   int arrivalTime;
   int CPUTime;
   int IOFrequency;
   int IODuration;

   int Ticks;
   int CPUConsumption;
   int CPUBurstSize;
   int queueNumber;
   int IOBurstCount;
   string state;
};
```

Comment: Holy... How did I miss that?

Comment: @MooingDuck: Usually we expect more 'advanced' errors, for lack of a better word :-)

Comment: Just when I wanted to write the 10th comment like "We don't need to see the whole process class", your answer comes along :)

Comment: Wow I am an idiot....thanks Andy don't know how I managed to do that. Thanks I guess I just needed a fresh pair of eyes!

@Excelcius I am never sure how much code to give....whenever I ask questions people always ask for more...

Comment: @user3372128: Make an SSCCE as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [here](http://www.sscce.org/).  That is _always_ the first step to asking a question about code.  The process of making an SSCCE will usually solve the problem for you

Comment: @Mooing Duck: thanks! I have generally tried to do that but I guess I guess I must summarize too much. Just need to find the sweet spot I guess :P

Comment: @user3372128 It's ok, that's what the comments are for. You don't have to include methods which are not used during construction of the object in this specific case, but of course, if you have no idea at all which part of the code is causing the issue, better to include all of it right away. And yes, an SSCCE is always a good idea.

Comment: @user3372128: There's no such thing as summarizing too much, if it's an SSCCE.  Maybe you made a short, but forgot the compilable and example(reproduces the problem) parts?

Comment: @Mooing Duck: perhaps that is it

Answer (score 3):

You defined global variables

```
int processId;
int arrivalTime;
int CPUTime;
int IOFrequency;
int IODuration;
```

and the constructor of class Process each time when it is called overrides their values.

```
Process::Process(int _processId, int _arrivalTime, int _CPUTime,
    int _IOFrequency, int _IODuration)
{
    processId = _processId;
    arrivalTime = _arrivalTime;
    CPUTime = _CPUTime;
    IOFrequency = _IOFrequency;
    IODuration = _IODuration;
    IOBurstCount = 0;
    CPUConsumption = 0;
    Ticks = 0;
    queueNumber = 0;
    //...
```

While the class itself has no data members.

So these global variables keep that values that were assigned to them in the last call of the constructor.